# Android JSch - package org.ietf.jgss does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ssh, jsch

I am trying to make an Android app with JSch. When I build, I get the following error:

```
error: package org.ietf.jgss does not exist
```

I understand this is a missing library, but I don't understand how I can fix this and use JSch in my app. Thanks in advance

Comment: org.ietf.jgss isn't related to jsch, as far as I know? Why do you think this error message has any implications for using jsch?

Comment: @Kenster I know because it's referenced in one of the jsch files.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: This error is caused by one file in JSch, com.jcraft.jsch.jgss.GSSContextKrb5.java.

This file is not required for SSH connections so I simply commented out the entire file.